# How to undo preventdefault in save event in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window

I have a Kendo Grid and set row save event as onAthleteGridSave. I want to add a custom window to set something similar to confirm box. Here is code

```
function onAthleteGridSave(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#AssignSport").data("kendoWindow").open();

    $("#AssignSport").find(".assignsportandsave,.notassignsportandsave")
        .click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("assignsportandsave")) {
            e.model.AssignSportId = $('#AssignEventId').data('kendoDropDownList').value();
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("notassignsportandsave")) {
            e.model.AssignSportId = "";
        }

        $("#AssignSport").data("kendoWindow").close();
    })
}    

<% Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("AssignSport")
    .Content(() =>
    { %>
        ...
        <input type="submit" class="assignsportandsave" value="Assign Sport And Save" />
        <input type="submit" class="notassignsportandsave" value="Not Assign Sport And Save" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="$('#AssignSport').data('kendoWindow').close();" />
     ...
     <%})
```

The problem is after clicking button in $("#AssignSport").data("kendoWindow"), the program can not go to controller action for Grid which is due to e.preventDefault().

But if removing e.preventDefault(), then program will not wait after $("#AssignSport").data("kendoWindow").open() and immediately go to controller action.

So I want to know if there is a way to undo e.preventDefault() or how to make program wait at where kendo window is opened for button information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't undo it, but you can save manually after making your changes to the model by calling [saveChanges()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-saveChanges). So something like this inside your click handler should work:

```
e.sender.saveChanges();
$("#AssignSport").data("kendoWindow").close();
```

Comment: Does it need to add something like "return true;"?

Comment: what do you mean with "it"

Comment: I mean in program after $("#AssignSport").data("kendoWindow").close(), is it needed to add "return true;" or some code else?

Comment: don't need to return anything